# Button reveal when hovering over image

Tags: html, css, hover

I am new to css and am trying to implement a functionality on my image which is - when someone hovers over the image with the mouse a 'Read More' button will be revealed. Here is the code I have so far -

HTML-

```
<div class="container"> 
   <img src="./images/pairingo.png">
   <div class="button"><a href="#">READ MORE</a></div>   
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container .button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

img{
     width:40%;
     height:40%
}

img:hover .button{
    opacity:1;
}
```

This doesnot seem to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong on the hover part? Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add hover css to .container class. Because img is child of .container class and .button is not child of img.

Try this.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.container .button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

img{
     width:100%;
}

.container:hover .button{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc/666?text=" class="img-responsive" alt="">
   <div class="button"><a href="#">READ MORE</a></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. But when I do that,I get hover effect on a much larger area than the image. Is there anyway I can set width and height of container to that of image.

Comment: Change the img width to 100%.

Comment: @SushmitChakraborty what I see from your code is in the `container` class you have provided `left` and `top` property so you need to choose those `%` on your requirement to get it fixed.

Comment: Thankyou. I changed hover to container and set my image width and height to that of container and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

> Set the `container`s `top` and `left` property to make your button visible wherever you need.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container .button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

img{
     width:80px;
     height:80px;
}

.container:hover .button{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
   <div class="button"><a href="#">READ MORE</a></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers! happy coding!